# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::select does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code

```
$post = DB::table('posts')
->join('post_images','post_images.post_id','=','posts.id')
->join('categories','categories.id','=','posts.category_id')
->orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')->paginate(15)
->select('posts.*','categories.title as category', 'post_images.image')
->get();
```

But I am getting **Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::select does not exist.**.

I need to paginate all the posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you get back from `paginate()` is already a collection and no longer the query builder, so you can't call `select()` on it. reorder your method calls and you should be fine.

```php
$post = DB::table('posts')
->join('post_images','post_images.post_id','=','posts.id')
->join('categories','categories.id','=','posts.category_id')
->orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')
->select('posts.*','categories.title as category', 'post_images.image')
->paginate(15);
```

Also, I would suggest, that you create a model and relationships if you are using Laravel/Eloquent - makes the whole thing easier. If you then need some extra magic that you want to have on multiple places, you should check out model scopes

Comment: There is a select method but it still throws this error https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-select